# Please help me to understand the use of "->" in Arrays.sort()

Tags: java

I was solving problems in GeeksforGeeks and suddenly got this. I understand the use of "Integer.compare", but could not get the use of "->" in the sortBySetBitCount method.

```
static void sortBySetBitCount(Integer arr[], int n)
{ 
    Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(countSetBit(b), countSetBit(a)));
         //I mean here the "->" operator
} 

static int countSetBit(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n>0) {
        n = n & (n - 1);
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: BTW instead of the `countSetBit` method, you could use [`Integer.bitCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int))

Comment: Read about [Lambda expressions in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) on the Oracle trails site.

Comment: Inside **countSetBit** method it should be **while( n != 0)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lambda expressions are added in Java 8 and provide below
> functionalities.
>
> Enable to treat functionality as a method argument, or code as data.
>
> A function that can be created without belonging to any class.
>
> A lambda expression can be passed around as if it was an object and executed on demand.

Syntax:

```
lambda operator -> body
```

where lambda operator can be:

Zero parameter:

```
() -> System.out.println("Zero parameter lambda");
```

One parameter:–

```
(p) -> System.out.println("One parameter: " + p);
```

It is not mandatory to use parentheses, if the type of that variable can be inferred from the context

Multiple parameters :

`(p1, p2) -> System.out.println("Multiple parameters: " + p1 + ", " +` p2);

Source for above examples [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/).

```
import java.util.*;

class MainClass{
    public static void main(String ... $){
        var out = System.out;
        Integer arr[] = {10, 32, 31};
        sortBySetBitCount(arr);
        //output is 31, 10, 32
        //31 has 5 set bits
        //10 has 3 set bits
        //32 has 1 set bit
        out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));

    }
    static void sortBySetBitCount(Integer arr[]){ 
        //first argument is array they we want to sort
        //second argument is a lambda method
        Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(countSetBit(b), countSetBit(a)));
    } 
    //Returns numbers of bit set
    static int countSetBit(int n) {
        int count = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            n = n & (n - 1);
            count += 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

### output:

```
$ javac MainClass.java && java MainClass 
[31, 10, 32]
```

More about lambda methods:

[Lambda method in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/)

Answer (score 3):

This is a part of the syntax of the new lambda expression introduced in Java 8. There are a couple of online tutorials to get the hang of it, Lambda Expression Document API [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

It is basically
**The symbol -> separates the parameters ( i.e left-side) from the implementation (i.e right side)**

The general syntax for using lambda expressions is

**(Parameters) -> { Body } where the -> separates parameters and lambda expression body.**

The parameters are enclosed in parentheses which is the same way as for methods and the lambda expression body is a block of code enclosed in braces.